# How do I change the background color of row when selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just created small task to calculate the total price of dishes.
When I click on submit order, the row of order dish need to be green. How can I do that in javascript?  I just want make background color of only those rows whose input box is checked to be set green and not of all rows.

```js
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.borderColor = "red";

function resetOrder() {

  event.preventDefault();

  myForm.reset();
  totalBillBox.innerText = "";

}

function billDo() {

  event.preventDefault();

  let orderedDishes = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
  let color = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');



  let totalBill = 0;

  orderedDishes.forEach((orderedDish) => {

    totalBill += +orderedDish.parentNode.previousElementSibling.innerText * orderedDish.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0].value;



  });



  if (totalBill >= 500) {

     

    var percent = 0.90 * totalBill;


    totalBillBox.innerText = percent;

  }

}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <table border="1">
    <h1 style="color: red;">Tabish Resturent</h1>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="download.jpg" </td>
        <td>Biryani</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><img src="download.jpg"></td>

      <td>Gajrela</td>
      <td>350</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>

      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number">
      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><img src="download.jpg" </td>

        <td>Malai Boti</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><img src="download.jpg" </td>

        <td>Qorma</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="mydiv">
      <td><img src="download.jpg" </td>

        <td>Mutton Soup</td>
        <td>650</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>
            <input type="number">
          </td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <button onclick="billDo()">Submit Order</button>
        <button onclick="resetOrder()">Reset Order</button>
        <button onclick="print()">Print Order</button>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" id="totalBillBox"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: When I run the snippet it gives an error.

Comment: Can you plz try it now

Comment: still gives an error

Answer (score -1):

Here's the jQuery answer:

```
$(document.ready(function () {
    var checkboxes = $("#myForm > table td > input[type='checkbox']");
    checkboxes.on("click", function () {
        checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").css({"background-color": "white"});
        checkboxes.filter(":checked").css({"background-color": "green"});
    });
});
```

You can, of course, do this without jQuery, but I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: I need to do that in JavaScript

Comment: This is javascript; jQuery is a javascript library, so all you need to do is download it from here https://jquery.com/download/ and embed it on your site.  But if you don't have permission to do that or something, then converting jQuery to vanilla javascript is normally mostly just a matter of looking up the equivalent functions.  document.QuerySelectorAll can be used in place of $, and .addEventListener() can be used in place of .on(), etc.